# Images only render on HTML5 website after turning device landscape (iOS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, html

Visit [www.tekiki.com](http://www.tekiki.com) from an iPhone. Make sure the device is on the cell network and not Wi-Fi, and the orientation is portrait.

Tap one of the apps, and scroll down. Screenshots of the app should appear at the bottom, but there are blank spaces representing the images.

Turn your device landscape, and the images suddenly appear.

Why don't the images appear until the device is turned in landscape mode?

Here's the relevant code:

```
    var screenshots_box = $( page ).find( '.screenshots_box' );
    screenshots_box.removeClass( 'loading' );
    screenshots.slice( 0, 4 );
    $( screenshots ).each( function() {
        var img = $( document.createElement('img') );

        // Set error handler, which refetches image
        img.error( function() { on_screenshot_load_error(img) });

        // Set image source
        img.attr( 'src', this );

        // Append new screenshot
        screenshots_box.append( img );
    });
```

Comment: No iPhone over here but the site is practically unusable in Opera Android 2.3

Comment: it's not meant for opera or android, but would you mind elaborating anyway? or perhaps post a screenshot? thanks.

Comment: I figured as much but I figured I'd would add some input either way. I managed to navigate to a game page, at which point everything froze :-/ So I couldn't scroll down to check the screenshots. Would've posted a screenshot but phone's not responding, sorry.